# Precedence Function

Tags: c++, stack

I'm trying to write a function, that goes within my main program, that will compare the precedence of operators being input by the user. The function would look for the following operators:

`+`, `-`, `*` , `/` with `*`, `/` having the highest precedence and `+`, `-` having the lowest precedence.

The operators with the lowest precedence go on the bottom of a stack while those with the highest precedence go on the top of the stack. So if a user types in `+-*/`, `*/+-` should be displayed in the terminal.

Any ideas on how I should go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read all of the operators into a `std::string`.  Write a function with the following type:

```
bool is_higher_precedence(char lhs, char rhs);
```

This function should return whether `lhs` has higher precedence than `rhs`.

You can then use this function as the functor parameter of `std::sort` to sort the operators by precedence.

Comment: Additional tip: You may care that sorting method you choose is a "stable sort." That is, two operators of equal precedence should stay in the same order they were in. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability

Answer (score 5):

Just sort them using `std::sort` with a custom predicate.

```
int precedence(char op)
{
    if (op == '*' || op == '/') return 0;
    return 1;
}

bool comparePrecedence(char a, char b)
{
    return precedence(a) < precedence(b);
}

int main()
{
    char input[] = "+-/";
    std::sort(input, input + 3, &comparePrecedence);
}
```

Obviously, you can add other operators simply by adding them into the `precedence` function.